# Opacity confliction when combining Graphics3D and ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting

When I combining `Graphics3D` and `ParametricPlot3D` in `Show`, the `Opacity` seems conflicted.

The following code use `Graphics3D` to draw a big circle,the opacity is 1.

```
   Show[
       Graphics3D@{Opacity[1], 
          Line[Table[{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], 0}, {\[Theta],0,2\[Pi],\[Pi]/120}]]},
       Boxed -> False, AspectRatio -> 1,PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
   ]
```

The opacity is normal currently:

[image]

Then I add a `ParametricPlot3D`(the inner sphere) with opacity 0.1, the opacity of origin circle(outer circle) becomes less than 1(but not 0.1,some value between 0.1 and 1):

[image]

The code with inner sphere:

```
Show[
 Graphics3D@{Opacity[1], 
   Line[Table[{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], 0}, {\[Theta], 0, 
      2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/120}]]},
 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  0.1*{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {u, 0, 
   2 \[Pi]}, {v, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.1]}, 
  Mesh -> None],
 
 Boxed -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
 ]
```

Comment: The line is not really transparent (you can see that when increasing the thickness using e.g. `AbsoluteThickness[3]`, but something is definitely changing with the rendering (running on Windows 10, Mathematica 12.3)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm running on Windows 10 too. Setting thickness solved my problem, thanks a lot.