# Rasterize drops anti-aliasing/changes axes thickness

Tags: graphics3d, visualization

When I `Export` a result of Rasterize, I seem to get a worse-quality image, compared to exporting image directly. Image dimensions are the same in both cases. The differences are that 1) 3D element antialiasing is less aggressive 2) plot axes are thicker after `Rasterize`. 3) text is more blurry (letters in "min" are merged)

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-rasterize-bug.nb)

It looks like Rasterize triggers a lower quality method, any tips how I can recover the higher quality pixels used by default `Export`?

I need Rasterize to control the number of pixels in the output image. Mathematica 12.3.1.0 on MacOS

Self-contained way to visualize the issue. The second image looks more jaggy, axes are darker and letters are merged together

```
circle = 
  SliceContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2, 
   z == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, Contours -> {1}, 
   ContourStyle -> Dashed, ContourShading -> None, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotRange -> All];

genPlot[theta_] := (plot1 = 
    Plot3D[3 x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, Mod[ArcTan[#1, #2], 2 Pi, theta] &}, 
     MeshStyle -> {Automatic, Thick}, 
     Mesh -> {5, {theta, theta + Pi}}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
     RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 1], 
     PlotPoints -> 25];
   point = {Cos[theta], Sin[theta], 0};
   plot2 = 
    Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], EdgeForm[None], 
      Polygon[{-point, point, 
        point + {0, 0, 10}, -point + {0, 0, 10}}]}];
   plot3d = 
    Show[plot1, plot2, circle, SphericalRegion -> True, 
     ImageSize -> 600];
   plot2d = 
    Plot[{x^2 + 3 y^2 /. {x -> Sin[theta]*d, y -> Cos[theta]*d}, 
      Labeled[3, Subscript[\[Lambda], max], {Above, Left}], 
      Labeled[1, Subscript[\[Lambda], min], {Above, Left}]}, {d, -1, 
      1}, PlotRange -> {0, 3.5}, 
     Ticks -> {{-1, 1}, {{1, ""}, {3, ""}}}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed, Dashed}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     ImageSize -> 300, 
     Epilog -> {Gray, Thin, Line[{{-1, 0}, {-1, 3.5}}], 
       Line[{{1, 0}, {1, 3.5}}], 
       Circle[{1, 3 Cos[theta]^2 + Sin[theta]^2}, .05]}];
   GraphicsRow[{plot3d, plot2d}]);

img = genPlot[Pi/2];
is = 200;
fn = "rotation-debug.gif";
Export[fn, img, ImageSize -> is];
Image[Import[fn], Magnification -> 5]

Export[fn, 
  Rasterize[img, ImageSize -> is, RasterSize -> is, 
   ImageResolution -> 1000]];
Image[Import[fn], Magnification -> 5]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: ``"12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 24, 2021)"`` produces exactly the same files, so the problem might be (as stated in the reference for ``Rasterize``) Mac-specific: _Images generated by Rasterize can vary slightly from one computer system to another, mainly as a result of different fonts and anti-aliasing procedures._ Have you tried using ``RenderingOptions`` in ``Show``? There is a parameter called ``"HardwareAntialiasingQuality"``. Also, changing ``"3DRenderingEngine"`` or ``"3DRenderingMethod"`` might help.

Comment: Are they both like the higher-quality screenshot, or the lower-quality screenshot?

Comment: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qraff.png)

Comment: I see....it looks like the high-quality antialiasing turns off for you as well -- compare the top-most pixels of the yellow solid

Comment: I think the problem is not really in ``Rasterize``, and it looks very similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251129/opacity-confliction-when-combining-graphics3d-and-parametricplot3d). Check it yourself: remove ``Opacity[0.5]`` from ``plot2`` and remove ``ContourShading -> None`` from ``circle``. You should see a difference. When using ``Show`` with (at least) one transparent graphics, the rendering somehow changes for _all_ the graphics ...

Comment: You are right, removing transparent elements makes the boundary smooth again. Now I just need a work-around to achieve this behavior that lets me specify both ImageSize and RasterSize for the resulting bitmap

Comment: BTW, I get high quality contours in Rasterize if I do `Style[img, RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "Mesa"}]`, but it changes text size in my 2D plot to be impossible to read. If I apply `Style` just to plot3d part before combining in GraphicsRow, it has no effect

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, I assume that both examples look near identical if you dropped all of the ImageSize, RasterSize, and ImageResolution specifications from `Export` and `Rasterize`.

Comment: @ihojnicki that seems to be the case, yes. However, I need RasterSize/ImageSize to export images for best display on retina screens for which images are rendered with 2x more pixels (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, if you want 2x then use `ImageResolution`.  `Export[fn, Rasterize[genPlot[Pi/2], ImageResolution -> 144]]`  If you need fixed dimensions for the bitmap, use `RasterSize`.  `ImageSize` isn't really necessary, that is determined by your content.  Specifying more than one often leads to contradictions.

Comment: `Export[Rasterize[img, ImageSize -> is, ImageResolution -> 72],...` gives jagged edges compared to `Export[img, ImageSize -> is]`, I suspect there's some extra magic done by ```System`Convert`CommonGraphicsDump`ExportElementsToRasterFormat["GIF", ##1]``` to make default export look smooth

Comment: as @Domen noticed earlier, this is connected to transparency. If I remove semi-transparent elements, I again get high quality antialiasing from Rasterize

Comment: On MacOSX 10.14.6, MMA 12.0.0.0 both methods produce identical images for me, I double checked using `ImageData[...]-ImageData[...]` on the imported images.

Comment: @N.J.Evans are they both high quality image, or low-quality image (jagged edges)?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I'd say they're both jagged - in fact they look considerably worse than the two images you have.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by John Fultz on wolfram [community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2367030), equivalent to default export is to Rasterize at 2x resolution and then downsample using `ImageResize` or `Export`:

```
Export["rotation.webp", Rasterize[#, ImageSize -> is, RasterSize -> 2 is], ImageSize -> is];
```

Notes (on MacOS):

- `Export[..., ImageSize->is]` generates image with `is` pixels
- `Export[Show[...,ImageSize->is]]` generates image with `2*is` pixels
- `Rasterize[ImageSize->is, RasterSize->2*is]` generates bitmap with `2*is` pixels

Therefore, rasterize with 2x number of pixels using `RasterSize->2*is` and then downsample to 1x pixels using `Export[...,ImageSize->is]`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Export["rotation-debug2.gif", Rasterize[img, RasterSize -> 700, ImageResolution -> 1000]]
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `Resolution` still gives me subpar-quality anti-aliasing....updated my post with an example where the difference is clear

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov Oh, I see, you're right.