# Creating animated gifs with less jitter?

Tags: export, visualization

I'm looking to improve the quality of exported animations (for which I'm limited to animated gifs for compatibility reasons), and the default export looks a bit unnatural/jittery. I'm wondering if there's a way to improve this. Potential ideas:

1. Simple motion blur
2. Temporal [antialiasing](https://ziyadbarakat.wordpress.com/2020/07/28/temporal-anti-aliasing-step-by-step/)

```
step = 10;
genPlot[i_] := 
  Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Rotate[Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}], i]}];
images = Table[genPlot[angle], {angle, 0, Pi - Pi/step, Pi/step}];
Export["circle.gif", images, "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity, 
 "DisplayDurations" -> 1/50]
```

[image]

Animation frames can be rendered at any time granularity, but gif frame delays are multiple of 10ms, so 25/50 FPS is possible, but 30/60 is not. Most displays nowadays seem to have refresh rate of 60 Hertz, so using 1/50 delay you would expect a "freeze-frame" every 5 frames. On other hand, this [video](https://vimeo.com/455807118) claims to be 50fps and looks smooth on my 60 Hz screen, so perhaps frame rate mismatch is not a significant contributor to jitter

**Edit**

simple blending makes it a bit better, but the line looks gray instead of black and the sector boundary looks clearly visible. Also 50x oversampling would be pretty expensive to compute for more general animations (ie, like this [one](https://machine-learning-etc.ghost.io/content/images/2021/08/dirichletBSP.gif))

```
radius = 50;
images2 = 
  Table[genPlot[angle], {angle, 0, Pi - Pi/(step*radius), 
    Pi/(step*radius)}];
images3 = Blend /@ Partition[images2, radius];
Export["circle2.gif", images3, "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity, 
 "DisplayDurations" -> 1/50]
```

[image]

Comment: You probably want to play with the frame durations in GIF. This [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4727/9469) may be relevant.

Comment: Perhaps you could play with different weights in the second argument of `Blend` to give more of a trailing effect. This might help darken up the line. Gamma correction via `ImageAdjust[im, {0, 0, γ}]` might help with that too.

Answer (score 6):

I ended up using `Blend` combined with a helper function below that creates weights from `Sin` curve to average several frames together.
[image]

IE, weights to smear each image over 5 frames, where each frame is a subsampled 3 times, the weights from `genWeights[5, 3]` look like this

[image]

```
(* generate sin plot centered at offset, 
 with given width . offset - width/2 .. offset + width/2 *)

makePlot[offset_, width_] := (
   (Cos[(2 \[Pi] (-offset + x))/width] + 1)/2
   );

(* generates weights for line spanning "spread" frames, each frame \
using "subsample" frames *)
genWeights[spread_, subsample_] := (
   Assert[OddQ[spread]];
   Assert[OddQ[subsample]];
   
   width = (spread*subsample - 1) + 2;
   middleFrame = (width - 2)/2;
   expr = makePlot[middleFrame, width];
   expr /. x -> # & /@ Range[0, spread*subsample - 1] // N
   );


spread = 5;
subsample = 3;
vals = genWeights[spread, subsample];
xvals = Transpose[{Range[Length[vals]], vals}]
ListPlot[Partition[xvals, subsample], InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Thickness[.05], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
 PlotLabel -> 
  StringForm["spread=``, subsample=``", spread, subsample]]
```

Comment: Very nice. How are the weights fed into `Blend`? If I understand correctly you feed in the entire half period of `Sin` as your weights? Would using the quarter period (from 0 to 1) make more sense? I wonder if it would give the line a black appearance on one side and a blur on the other (a trailing effect).

Comment: It's done with `Blend[images[[#]], weights] & /@ Partition[Range[totalFrames], 15, 3]`. I'll experiment some more with half blending some on realistic images, currently my rotation animations like [the ones here](https://machine-learning-etc.ghost.io/p/765acb0d-0985-4f91-8db5-d9457f11425f/) are looking jerky

Comment: Wow, `Blend` is slow on Graphics3D, much slower than Export or Rasterize, I ran out of patience waiting for 10 frames to Blend together, may need to do a combo Mathematica+Python solution for this, https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-blending-rotation.nb

Comment: FWIW `Blend[Rasterize /@ frames[[#]], weights]` is 6 times faster than `Blend[frames[[#]], weights]` on my machine. A bit more bearable. You could also look into using `ParallelMap` -- when doing so you'll need to wrap your call to `Blend` in `UsingFrontEnd` to invoke a sub front end.

Comment: Thanks, thought about using Rasterize too, currently figuring out how to get rid of the quality drop I see with Rasterize -- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255544/rasterize-drops-anti-aliasing-changes-axes-thickness